# Next Sequential Number from DataGridView Data in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to Visual Basic. Net.

I am making one form in which the employee id will be next sequential number after checking the data from the datagridview.

Below is my code:

```
Sub GetEmployeeiD()
    Dim id As Integer
    Dim dg As DataGridView = dgvdata


    If dg.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        id = 1
        Me.txtid.Text = id
    ElseIf dg.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        id = dg.Rows.Count + 1
        Me.txtid.Text = id
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is as of now i have two records in my datagridview and when i click "Add", it should generate the next sequential id i.e. 3, but it is generating 4.

Please advise where i am wrong.

Thanks
Salman

Comment: Why even use that if statement?  The row at the bottom that is used to add new rows counts as a row, too.  GetBlahBlah sounds like a function, that it should return something.

Comment: You know that once you delete a record, the count wont sync up with the last id and you will be issuing possibly multiple dupes.  Thats  one reason it is best to let the DB do its job and issue unique IDs

Comment: @Plutonix  I understand your point but the thing is deleting a record will not delete the record from the DB though it will just inactive it. Thats why i am using code to generate the iD

Comment: So your grid will *always* show inactive records?  Because if it doesn't, your id sequence will be duplicating.  The id should always be generated by the database.

Comment: @LarsTech so you are suggesting me to go for autonumber option of the database.